# Reduce memory consumption by Powershell script

Tags: performance, powershell, memory

I'm using this Powershell script to retrieve info of remote servers from a central server.

In this case, there are about 150 servers on Active Directory:

```
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "...*"' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($computer in $Servers) 
{
  try 
  {
    $ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
    
    $IP = ($ping.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString            
    $hardware = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop
    $totalMemory = (Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $computer | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum /1gb
    $os = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer 
    $cpu = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_processor -ComputerName $computer | Group-Object -Property Name | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, 
                              @{Name = 'TotalSockets'; Expression = {$_.Count}}, 
                              @{Name = 'TotalCores'; Expression = {($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property NumberOfCores -Sum).Sum}}, 
                              @{Name = 'TotalLogicalProcessors'; Expression = {($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors -Sum).Sum}}                                                                       
                              
    #$disks = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -ComputerName $computer -Filter "DriveType='3'" | Sort-Object Name                        
   
    # create new custom object to keep adding store information to it
  $Result = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
  ComputerName                         = $computer.ToUpper()
  IPAddress                            = $IP
  Manufacturer                         = $hardware.Manufacturer
  Model                                = $hardware.Model
  ADDescription                        = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -Properties Description).Description -join ';'
  ProductName                          = $os.Caption
  OSVersion                            = $os.version
  BuildNumber                          = $os.BuildNumber
  OSArchitecture                       = $os.OSArchitecture     
  Domain                               = $hardware.Domain
  'RAM (GB)'                           = $totalMemory
  CPU                                  = $cpu.Name
  CPUTotalSockets                      = $cpu.TotalSockets
  CPUTotalCores                        = $cpu.TotalCores
  CPUTotalLogicalProcessors            = $cpu.TotalLogicalProcessors
  CPUVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled     = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_processor -ComputerName $computer).VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled -join ','
                                   
 }  
 # Column ordering, re-order if you like 
 <#$colOrder = 'ComputerName', 'IPAddress', 'Manufacturer', 'Model', 'ADDescription',
           'ProductName', 'OSVersion', 'BuildNumber', 'OSArchitecture', 
           'Domain', 'RAM (GB)', 'CPU', 'CPUTotalSockets', 'CPUTotalCores',
           'CPUTotalLogicalProcessors', 'CPUVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled'#>

 # Return all your results
 #$Result | Select-Object -Property $colOrder
 $Result | Select-Object "ComputerName", "IPAddress", "Manufacturer", "Model", "ADDescription", "ProductName", "OSVersion", "BuildNumber", 
                       "OSArchitecture", "RAM (GB)", "CPU", "CPUTotalSockets", "CPUTotalCores", "CPUTotalLogicalProcessors", "CPUVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled", "Domain" |
           Export-Csv -Path "C:\SQL\Get-Inventory.csv" -Delimiter '|' -Append -NoTypeInformation
 #$disks | Format-Table DriveLetter, Label, @{Name='Size(GB)'; Expression={[decimal]('{0:N0}' -f($_.Capacity/1gb))}}, @{Name='FreeSpace(GB)'; Expression={[decimal]('{0:N0}' -f($_.FreeSpace/1gb))}}
}
 catch 
 { Write-Output "--- $computer ---" $Error[0] `n | Add-Content -Path C:\SQL\UnreachableServers.txt }
```

}

The Powershell's process uses an average of 50/75 Mb of RAM. It's possible to reduce the RAM usage?

I accept any kind of advice given my little experience on Powershell :)

Thanks in advance.

Alessandro

Comment: May I ask *why* you need to reduce it? 50-75MB of memory doesn't seem that bad?

Comment: For instance, just running Powershell 7 with a small script that simply outputs a string and waits for a keypress takes 48.6MB on my computer. That's probably a good baseline *just for loading Powershell*.

Comment: you are making multiple calls to each remote system. if you switch to using `Invoke-Command` you can make ONE call to each system ... and run the code over there. that otta reduce your RAM & CPU use somewhat. [*grin*]

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, can u provide me an example of how to use the Invoke-Command in my case?

Comment: Hi @LasseV.Karlsen, thanks for your reply. So the average of 70 Mb of RAM can be considered a normal value?

Comment: @Alessandro How much memory does PowerShell consume on your system if you start `powershell.exe` without running your script? And how exactly are you measure it? `(ps -id $pid).WorkingSet64 / 1MB`?

Comment: take a look at this >>> basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH

Comment: Please answer the question in first comment ***why you need to reduce this already small amount of memory?*** (add that to the question). I suspect there is more behind this as normally for PowerShell the memory usage shouldn't change whether there is **1** or **150** servers to *stream* through your function.

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, if I don't run the script, the Powershell's process uses 50-55 Mb of RAM

Comment: Hi @iRon, given my little experience in Powershell and in general with programming, I wanted to know if it was a good baseline or if the code could be optimized.